# Wordpress registration confirmation email contains 'Click to set' password link - is this the expected behaviour?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, authentication, registration

Each new user on my Wordpress site gets a registration confirmation email that includes a 'Click to set' password link which takes them to the password reset screen. Once they have reset the password the admin gets a password reset email. This is not the way it used to work on my Wordpress sites, as users used to get their password emailed to them in the registration email.

Has there been a change to the default registration process?  I briefly installed the [Theme My Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/) plugin, and I have heard that this can cause issues, even when uninstalled, and I have followed instructions to fully uninstall, but I don't know whether this is the issue, or whether what I am seeing is the expected behaviour. It seems strange to me that a password reset process would be initiated on first registration, and I would like the user to be emailed a password instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, its a much safer way.

You can still set a password in single Wordpress installations but in MU users will be sent a reset password link.

Comment: Thanks. Mine is a single Wordpress installation. How would I go about sending a password instead of a reset password link? I appreciate that the reset password link is safer, but I'm trying to troubleshoot another issue and would at least like to test with the old method of sending a password to new users.

Comment: You could always use the hooks, start looking at register_post or user_register. Im sure they will send you in right direction. Or try a custom email registration email plugin, eg. https://wordpress.org/plugins/welcome-email-editor/